# Dead man's switch in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to implement a [Dead man's switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch) in Kotlin. What this does is fire a notification `TIME_INTERVAL` seconds after the last `MyEvent` was received. When a new `MyEvent` is received, it restarts the timer.

```
private val stopWatch = object : () -> Unit {
  var timer = System.currentTimeMillis()
  var isRunning = false

  override fun invoke() {
    timer = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (isRunning) return
    synchronized(this) {
      isRunning = true

      while (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer <= TIME_INTERVAL) {}

      fireNotification()
      isRunning = false
    }
  }
}

override fun onSomeEvent(e: MyEvent?) {
  runAsync(stopWatch)
}
```

Is there a simpler or easier way to get this functionality by using either the `kotlin.concurrent` or Java standard libraries?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your code consists in looping doing nothing until the time interval has elapsed. This is a bad idea, since it consumes a whole lot of CPU doing nothing, instead of just waiting.

I would use a ScheduledExecutr to schedule the firing of the notification. And I would cancel the returned future when an event comes in before the notification is fired:

```
import java.time.Instant.now
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class StopWatch {
    private var future: ScheduledFuture<Void>? = null;
    private val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

    fun onSomeEvent() {
        synchronized(this) {
            future.let {
                future?.cancel(false)
                future = null
            }

            val command = {
                synchronized(this@StopWatch) {
                    future = null
                }
                fireNotification()
                null
            }
            future = executor.schedule(command, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }
        println("${now()} - event")
    }

    private fun fireNotification() {
        println("${now()} - notification")
    }

    fun shutdown() {
        executor.shutdown()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val stopWatch = StopWatch()
    stopWatch.onSomeEvent()
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    stopWatch.onSomeEvent()
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    stopWatch.onSomeEvent()
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    stopWatch.onSomeEvent()
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    stopWatch.onSomeEvent()
    stopWatch.shutdown()
}
```

Which prints:

```
2017-05-07T12:45:55.647Z - event
2017-05-07T12:45:56.741Z - event
2017-05-07T12:45:57.743Z - event
2017-05-07T12:45:58.745Z - event
2017-05-07T12:46:00.747Z - notification
2017-05-07T12:46:01.750Z - event
2017-05-07T12:46:03.753Z - notification
```

Comment: Thanks! The empty loop is just by example, ie. I could just as easily sleep. For example:
`while (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer <= 2000) {Thread.sleep(Math.abs(2000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer)))}`. Also     `private var future: ScheduledFuture<Void>? = null;` is a pattern I would rather avoid.